# How to escape quotes inside an inline javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function is running perfectly without using class in appended `div` but when I try to add a `class` on the element it is not working.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showt(id){
            $('body').append(id)
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" id="hidemain" onmouseover='showt("<div class='sdf'>appended</div>")'>show detail</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Why don't you bind the event handler in your script, instead of inline on the element?

Comment: variable name 'id' is not really accurate here

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to get pageX from this function

Comment: @jchand what is `pageX`? It's not specified in your code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just escape quotes, when used inside other quotes. Also just use the respective other quotes inside the attribute. So if you enclose the attribute in `"` just use `'` and `\'` inside and vica verse. (Thanks to @nnnnnn for mentioning this!)

```
<a href="#" id="hidemain" onmouseover="showt('<div class=\'sdf\'>appended</div>')">show detail</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" id="hidemain" onmouseover='showt("<div class=\"sdf\">appended</div>')">show detail</a>
```

**EDIT**

In order to get the event object, you should add the event handler programatically like this:

```
<a href="#" id="hidemain">show detail</a>
<script>
  document.getElementById( 'hidemain' ).addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
    showt( '<div class="sdf">appended</div>' );
    // here you have access to event and thus event.pageX
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I would like to suggest to use **double quotes** for HTML codes.

Comment: Thanks it is working. I want to know one more thing, how to get pageX in from this function

Comment: Did you test the escaping directly in the html? Doesn't work in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/cFw4U/ (not sure about other browsers). It needs to use the opposite type of quote to whatever is around the html attribute...

Answer (score 6):

Since you tagged your question with jQuery, here's the jQuery version using a `mouseover` handler instead of a `onmouseover` attribute, which negates the escaping of quotes altogether.

```
<head>
    <!-- include jquery.js here -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#hidemain').mouseover(function() {
                showt('<div class="sdf">appended</div>');
            });
        });

        function showt(id){
            $('body').append(id)
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" id="hidemain">show detail</a>
</body>
```

Comment: I just posted the same answer, damn.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you already are using jQuery, you instead do this:

```
$(function() {
    function showt(domElement){
        $('body').append(domElement)
    }

    $("#hidemain").mouseover(function() {
        showt($("<div />").addClass("sdf").text("test"));
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the embedded quotes with `\`:

```
<a href="#" id="hidemain" onmouseover='showt("<div class=\"sdf\">appended</div>")'>show detail</a>
```

Note that also I changed the inner quotes to doubles as well as escaping them because if outer quotes are around an html element attribute using the same type of quote within may not work even when escaped.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
onmouseover='showt("<div class=\'sdf\'>appended</div>")'
```

these quotes needs to be escaped `'\'`.