# Click event do not work to child elements of dynamic created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm working with bootstrap-colorpicker in order to fill a color input value with a simple graphic content.
In order to give some "tip colors" I tried to append the default bootstrap-colorpicker with some other colors. It looks like this:

[image: Default]

[image: With modification]

In order to achieve this I added the following code to end of page. It basically let's colorpicker loads by it self and then append the desired div with the elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".colorpicker-color").remove();
    $('<div style="display: block;width:130px;height:100px;/* float: right; */position: absolute;top: 104px;/* overflow-y: scroll; */"><div><small class="text-muted">Sugestões:</small><div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;padding:5px;height: 60px;overflow-y: scroll;"><i class="fas fa-circle" style="top: 0px;margin:5px;color:#aaa;cursor:pointer" id="color_0" onclick=" alert('im working');"></i></div></div> </div>').insertAfter(".colorpicker-hue");
    $(".colorpicker").css("height","185px");
  }, 500);
});
```

The problem is that the click event to the fas fa-circle is not working. 
I place alert("im working"); just for testing proposes. I't won't show up on clicking.

The resulting code after jquery adds the elements it's the following:

```
[![resulting code][3]][3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the answers have excellent advice for you, but they may have missed the problem. In fact, Ludovico gave you the answer but it was quietly included with his other very useful information so perhaps you missed it.

You are encountering something called ***event delegation***. That means, items newly added into the DOM do not have click bindings associated with them (even though you defined them in code) *because they were not in the DOM when the click events were bound to the appropriate elements.*

*(Note that "the DOM" is basically the* ***living*** *webpage as it appears on your screen - with all real-time mods from javascript, etc. So it is more than just the HTML code.)*

Very simple to solve this, using jQuery.

Instead of:

```
$('#myID').click(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

do this instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myID', function(){
    //your code here
});
```

What this does is bind the click event to something that *does* exist at the time the DOM is rendered (i.e. the "document" object) - and jQuery's `.on()` method now watches the DOM for anything else being inserted. If any new element matches the specified element, then the click event is bound to that element *whenever it appears in the DOM*.

References:

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

https://api.jquery.com/on/

http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should try to avoid inline event handlers like `onclick`, especially when working with jQuery, which itself provides a fairly flexible interface for event binding.

You could take this approach instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".colorpicker-color").remove();

    $(".colorpicker").css("height","185px");


    /* Compose suggestions into a local variable */
    var suggestions = $('<div style="display:block; width:130px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:104px;"><div><small class="text-muted">Sugestões:</small><div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;padding:5px;height: 60px;overflow-y: scroll;"><i class="fas fa-circle" style="top: 0px;margin:5px;color:#aaa;cursor:pointer" id="color_0"></i></div></div> </div>')

    /* select .fas elements from suggestions and assign click handler that way */
    $('.fa-circle', suggestions).click(function() {

        alert("I'm working");
        return false;
    })

    /* Insert suggestions */
    suggestions.insertAfter(".colorpicker-hue");
  }, 500);
})
```

Comment: but if I use diferent icons with diferent ids?

Comment: @FábioAraújo just updated answer to use `.fa-circle` instead - does that help?

Answer (score 0):

The code used to create and insert your DOM elements is not properly formatted. There are unscapped quotes inside other quotes:

[image]

To solve this, you can scape the inner quotes of this long string (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231089/how-to-escape-quotes-inside-an-inline-javascript-function) for more details) but I'd rather recommend you declare your event handler in a separate statement (this will make your code easier to read and maintain):

```
$('body').on("click", ".fa-circle", function() {
    alert("click!");
});
```

---

Also, I strongly recommend you extract all the inline CSS. It will make your life much easier. Something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".colorpicker-color").remove();
    $('<div id="container"><div><small class="text-muted">Sugestões:</small><div id="inner"><i class="fas fa-circle" id="color_0"></i></div></div> </div>').insertAfter(".colorpicker-hue");
    $(".colorpicker").css("height","185px");
  }, 500);

  $('body').on("click", ".fa-circle", function() {
    alert("I'm working!");
  });

});
</script>

<style>
#container{
  display: block;width:130px;height:100px;/* float: right; */position: absolute;top: 104px;/* overflow-y: scroll; */
}
#inner {
  display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;padding:5px;height: 60px;overflow-y: scroll;
}
#color_0{
  top: 0px;margin:5px;color:#aaa;cursor:pointer
}
</style>
```

Comment: I just placed a bad example. Even with a not scaped string it won't work anyway.

Comment: Best thing you can do is to organize your code to make it more readable (for example, extract your inline css), this will make much easier for you to identify what is not correct

Comment: It don't work. I think thats because colorpicker it's kind a "popup" and closes when I click and somehow prevents default click event of my dynamic added icon elements