# Why is the onClick() not responding

Tags: javascript, html

So I was creating a simple calculator for Area and perimeter of circles. I stored the code in JavaScript and called it on the `onClick()`, however, the `innerHtml` is not changing at all.

```js
calculate(radius) {
  cal_area = String(Math.PI * (radius * radius));
  cal_perimeter = String(Math.PI * (radius * 2));
  document.getElementById("Area").innerHTML = cal_area;
  document.getElementById("Perimeter").innerHTML = cal_perimeter;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Circles</title>
  <script src="brain.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="Radius" placeholder="Radius">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate(radius = document.getElementById("Radius").value;);">
  </form>
  <br>
  <p id="Area">test</p>
  <br>
  <p id="Perimeter">test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use single quotes inside the `onclick` value. `document.getElementById('Radius')` otherwise you close the attribute and start a new one. You also don't need the `radius=`s,  it is assigned in the function definition.

Comment: Also that assignment operation in the method invocation is unnecessary.  Just pass in the radius value, or look up the radius value in the method

Comment: Did you try the debug console in your browser? It feels there is some error blocking the innerHTML change.

Comment: Don't mix submit inputs with onclick.  Either attach your function to the submit event of the form or make it type "button" instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape quotes inside an inline javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231089/how-to-escape-quotes-inside-an-inline-javascript-function)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using something more along the lines of the following. You need to use singly quotes around Radius because you already have a double quote before the word calculate, so it's cutting short. You also don't need to assign a variable in your HTML, just pass through document.getElementById('Radius').value

```
<input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate(document.getElementById('Radius').value)">
```

Also you should include the word function before your function

```
function calculate(radius){
  cal_area = String(Math.PI * (radius * radius));
  cal_perimeter = String(Math.PI * (radius * 2));
  document.getElementById("Area").innerHTML = cal_area;
  document.getElementById("Perimeter").innerHTML = cal_perimeter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `"Radius"`with double quotes type `'Radius'` with single quotes in your `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

There is bit of refactoring is needed in your code. Eg. "double quotes" and "value assignment". I have modified your code. Take a look below

```js
function calculate() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var radius = document.getElementById("Radius").value;
  var cal_area = String(Math.PI * (radius * radius));
  var cal_perimeter = String(Math.PI * (radius * 2));
  document.getElementById("Area").innerHTML = cal_area;
  document.getElementById("Perimeter").innerHTML = cal_perimeter;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Circles</title>
  <script src="brain.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="Radius" placeholder="Radius">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()">
  </form>
  <br>
  <p id="Area">test</p>
  <br>
  <p id="Perimeter">test</p>
</body>
```

If you see above code, I have made following changes

1. I added `event.preventDefault();` in the function. This will stop page refresh on click.
2. I removed the value assignment from the HTML. I changed `onclick="calculate(radius = document.getElementById("Radius").value;);"` to `onclick="calculate()"`.
3. I accessing the value of `radius` in function itself. `var radius = document.getElementById("Radius").value;`

Answer (score 0):

you are performing an assignment within the call, and it is a horror it must be done in the function itself.

in this example i had added "event.preventDefault()" in this way you can stop the page refresh .

```js
function calculate(radius) {
  var cal_area = String(Math.PI * (radius * radius));
  var cal_perimeter = String(Math.PI * (radius * 2));
  document.getElementById("Area").innerText = cal_area;
  document.getElementById("Perimeter").innerText = cal_perimeter;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Circles</title>
  <script src="brain.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="Radius" placeholder="Radius">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate(document.getElementById('Radius').value)">
  </form>
  <br>
  <p id="Area">test</p>
  <br>
  <p id="Perimeter">test</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function calculate(radius) {
  event.preventDefault()
  var cal_area = String(Math.PI * (radius * radius));
  var cal_perimeter = String(Math.PI * (radius * 2));
  var Area =document.getElementById("Area").innerText = cal_area;
  var Peri=document.getElementById("Perimeter").innerText = cal_perimeter;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Circles</title>
  <script src="brain.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="Radius" placeholder="Radius" value="0">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate(document.getElementById('Radius').value)">
  </form>
  <br>
  <p id="Area">test</p>
  <br>
  <p id="Perimeter">test</p>
</body>

</html>
```